# How to set dynamic width and height for iframe in App Part

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app, iframe, app-part

My app part doesn't support responsiveness height and width.

I have tried to set height using app, but it's not working.

So how can I make App part responsive

Here is some view source of App part

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a resize event on the page with alters the Iframes inline styles

Comment: No not yet. do you any something in mind

Comment: Hmm.. let me think.. as they are inline styles you can never target them with higher Specificity CSS or CSS media queries.... [thinking] ... wait... I got it!!  Use a window resize event to change the inline width & height style on that IFrame....

Answer (score 2):

If the app part is SharePoint OOTB modal then use below javascript

```
var dlg = SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog();
if (dlg != null) {
      dlg.autoSize();
}
```

Hope this helps.